# Why in Braintree paypal button is not visible using drop-in form in production(live) account api credentials

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment, credit-card, braintree

When i'm using sandbox account for drop-in form of braintree then card fields and paypal button is visible.

[image]

But on production account API credentials then paypal button is not visible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

My suspicion is that your production account is not configured to accept PayPal, which will prevent the button from even showing up in the Drop-in. Ensure that you have configured and verified a [PayPal Business Account](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/setup-guide#sign-up-for-a-paypal-business-account), and that it is [enabled in the Control Panel](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/setup-guide#enter-your-paypal-credentials-in-the-braintree-control-panel). Once it is enabled, the button should automatically appear in instances of your Drop-in UI, or you can include it [separately](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/javascript/v2).

If you have any trouble setting up your account, or if your account is enabled for PayPal and the button still doesn't show, please reach out to [Braintree support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).