# Accepted payment method does not show paypal

Tags: paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

Sandbox account does not show PayPal in accept payment method

I have tried my account login with pay pal account but in may app PayPal checkout option redirecting on PayPal  account what I do  in sandbox account

advance in thanks

[image]

Comment: I believe these are setup by Braintree. I would drop them a line to see if they can add PayPal to your accepted methods.

Comment: i am login with paypal in sandbox account but does not working

Comment: Please ensure that you have configured your Braintree account to accept PayPal. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39150843/5261045). If you have further trouble, reach out to Braintree support at support@braintreepayments.com.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why in Braintree paypal button is not visible using drop-in form in production(live) account api credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138929/why-in-braintree-paypal-button-is-not-visible-using-drop-in-form-in-productionl)