# Braintree iOS drop in doesn't show PayPal

Tags: ios, braintree

I am trying trying to use the Braintree Dropin UI in my iOS app.

I am testing in the sandbox, and it works fine, but only accepts cards - not PayPal?

I am just using the provided code for objective C.

The docs say `Add the Drop-in UI with a few lines of code to get a full-featured checkout with credit card and PayPal payments.` - but where is my PayPal button??

```
- (void)showDropIn:(NSString *)clientTokenOrTokenizationKey {
BTDropInRequest *request = [[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];
BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:clientTokenOrTokenizationKey request:request handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    } else if (result.cancelled) {
        NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
    } else {
        // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
        // result.paymentOptionType
        // result.paymentMethod
        // result.paymentIcon
        // result.paymentDescription
    }
}];
[self presentViewController:dropIn animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image: iOS Screenshot (o]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the developers page says:

> By default, Drop-in only ships with support for cards. You can include additional payment methods by adding their respective pods.

You  must add these options:

```
    Ruby
pod 'Braintree/PayPal'
pod 'Braintree/Venmo'
pod 'Braintree/Apple-Pay'
pod 'Braintree/3D-Secure'
```

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/ios/v4#pods

Comment: Thank you so much - don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you have missed adding LSApplicationQueriesSchemes:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/ios/v4#register-a-url-type

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added those, but I am seeing `-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.paypal.ppclient.touch.v1://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"` in the logs?

Comment: Can you provide (or make a gist of) your info.plist?

Comment: Do you have PayPal installed on the device? Does it work if you do install the PayPal app?

It should show PayPal in both scenarios but installing the app should make that log item go away.

A full log would also help.

Comment: I tried that - makes no difference. None of the three url types in the info.plist are not recognised after installing the app. I though it should use a web view as fallback anyway?

Comment: Do you have your sandbox PayPal account linked to Braintree?

The reason I ask is that this JS issue is very similar to the issue you are having:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138929/why-in-braintree-paypal-button-is-not-visible-using-drop-in-form-in-productionl

This link might help:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/ruby#linked-paypal-testing

Comment: Have you add these lines? `pod 'Braintree/PayPal'
pod 'Braintree/Venmo'
pod 'Braintree/Apple-Pay'
pod 'Braintree/3D-Secure'` to the pods? https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/ios/v4#pods

Answer (score 0):

add this to the request

```
request.paypalDisabled = false
```